# Can compass compile css selectors on separate lines?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

`compass compile --output-style expanded` compiles as such:

```
.story, .passage {
 color: blue;
}
```

I would like it to compile with each selector on its own line:

```
.story,
.passage {
 color: blue;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no formatter property that will allow that.

Comment: All compiled CSS that is going to be used live should be minified.